# .htaccess clean url with two variables

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Well i already tried many codes but still cant figured it out whats the correct one to make it working.

Well i got this code:

```
#--Redirect from "/?page=foo" to "/page/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/page/foo/" to "/?page=foo"--#
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#--Redirect from "/search.php?search=foo" to "/search/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/search/foo/" to "/search.php?search=foo"--#
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

#--Redirect from "/post.php?id_post=foo" to "/post/foo"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /post\.php\?id_post=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/post/foo/" to "/post.php?id_post=foo"--#
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/?$ /post.php?id_post=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Support new SEO-friendly URLs
RewriteRule page/(.*) ?page=$1
RewriteRule search/(.*) search.php?search=$1
RewriteRule post/(.*) post.php?id_post=$1
```

and they are working pretty fine but now i would like to make one joining 2 of them like:

```
RewriteRule search/(.*)/page/(.*) search.php?search=$1&page=$2
```

The link works pretty fine but the url doesnt change automatically like the others upper i would like to know if its possible and if yes please help :)

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Well, you can see the pattern being used in the others. There is first a condition and rule to redirect the old format to the new format, and then a rule to rewrite then new format back to the old/actual format. So follow the same principal for this new one, and you'll be all set.

Comment: i already tried and didnt work it i can paste here what i did and you could fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

#--Redirect from "/search.php?search=foo&page=bar" to "/search/foo/page/bar"--#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search=([^&]+)&page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/page/%2? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/search/foo/page/bar" to "/search.php?search=foo&page=bar"--#
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/page/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?search=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```